# Cómo imprimir un archivo con formato CSV utilizando SWIFT?

Tags: swift, csv, impresión

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en `Swift 3`, y hago uso de archivos con formato `CSV` y quisiera saber si existe una forma de mandar a imprimir ese archivo en una impresora.

Los datos de la tabla, son los que recolecto en el archivo `.CSV`, sin embargo yo quisiera saber si existe una forma de imprimir esa tabla desde el `iPhone`, o usando `Swift`?

[image: tabla]

Comment: Se puede hacer un .html con esos datos y ese formato de tabla y luego utilizar Core Graphics para convertirlo en pdf y de esa manera imprimirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Para convertir el *PDF* en una estructura manejable, podés usar [CHCSVParser](http://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser). Creo que tu mejor opción es pasarlo a un `NSString`

Después para **dibujar** el *PDF*, podés usar ***Core Graphics***. Para mas información podés ver la documentación oficial de *Apple* con ejemplos y después tenés la guía para usar ***Quartz 2D***.

Un ejemplo de código simple:

```
// Crear la URl del archivo PDF
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = @"test.pdf";
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:documentsDirectory, filename, nil]];

// Crear el contexto del pdf
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, NULL, NULL);
CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);

// Configurar sistema de coordenadas
CGRect bounds = CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(pdfContext);
CGContextScaleCTM(pdfContext, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0.0, -bounds.size.height);

// Dibujar Un string (Puede ser un attributed string)
[@"Hola Mundo" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:72.0f]];

// Limpieza
UIGraphicsPopContext();
CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);
```

[Documentación de Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) y [Quartz 2D](http://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW6) (enlaces en inglés).